# Owlready2 access axioms

Tags: python, python-3.x, ontology, owlready

I am having trouble accessing the axioms of classes of an existing ontology. I know that some class contains an axiom that I need. For example the class "cold" contains the axioms:

Cold ⊓ Beer ⊑ Positive, and

Cold ⊓ Pizza ⊑ Negative

Is there a way to access these?

```
from owlready2 import *   

onto_path.append("\Path_to_owl_file")
onto = get_ontology("some_owl_file.owl")
onto = onto.load()

classes = list(onto.classes()) # Get all classes from the ontology

first_class = classes[0]
# Access axioms from this class
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://owlready.8326.n8.nabble.com/Accessing-the-axioms-and-axiom-closure-of-an-ontology-td217.html